# LINQ lambda optimization .NET 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have an EF Core repository function with lambda LINQ, used to read a home object with all of it's related objects:

```
public HomeObj ReadByIdWithObjects(int id)
{
   var home = _context.Instance.Homes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Home_id == id);

   if (home == null) 
       return null;

   home.Seller = _context.Instance
                         .Sellers
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Seller_id == home.Seller_id);

   home.Address = _context.Instance
                          .Addresses
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address_Id == home.Address_Id);

   home.Owner = _context.Instance
                        .Owners
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Owner_id == home.Owner_id);

   home.Events = _context.Instance
                         .Events
                         .Where(x => x.Home_id == home.Home_id)
                         .ToList();

   return home;
}
```

The problem with this function is it reads the full home object, and the full related objects, even though only a few of the properties are used. Wanting to optimize this, I tried rewriting this using `.include()` thinking joining tables in a single call, and then selecting only what's needed will be more efficient than 5 separate DB connections.

The new function:

```
public HomeObj ReadByIdWithObjects(int id)
{
     var home = context.Instance.Homes
    .Where(x => x.Home_id == id)
    .Include(x => x.Seller)
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .Include(x => x.Events)
    .Select(x => new HomeObj
    {
        Home_id = x.Home_id,
        Number = x.Number,
        Color = x.Color,
        DateBuilt = x.DateBuilt,
        Address = new Address
        {
            Id = x.Address.Id
            UPRN = x.Address.UPRN,
            Address_Address = x.Address.Address_Address,
            Town = x.Address.Town,
            Postcode = x.Address.Postcode
        },
        Owner = new Owner
        {
            Owner_id = x.Owner.Owner_id,
            Owner_Name = x.Owner.Owner_Name
        },
        Events = x.Events,
    }).FirstOrDefault();

 return home;
}
```

To my surprise, the new function took much longer to execute. I debugged it, and tried to get the generated SQL, and this is what I got:

```
DECLARE @__id_0 int = 2114465;

SELECT [h].[Home_id], [h].[Number], [h].[Color], [h].[DateBuilt], 
[a].[Id], [a].[UPRN], [a].[Address_Address], [a].[Town], [a].[Postcode], 
[o].[Owner_id], [o].[Owner_Name],
[e1].[Event_id], [e1].[Owner_id], [e1].[Event_created], [e1].[Event_text],
[e2].[Event_id], [e2].[Owner_id], [e2].[Event_created], [e2].[Event_text]
FROM [Home] AS [h]
INNER JOIN [Address] AS [a] ON [h].[Address_Id] = [a].[Address_Id]
INNER JOIN [Owner] AS [o] ON [h].[Owner_id] = [h].[Owner_id]
LEFT JOIN [Event] AS [e1] ON [h].[Home_id] = [e1].[Home_id]
LEFT JOIN [Event] AS [e2] ON [h].[Home_id] = [e2].[Home_id]
WHERE [a].[Home_id] = @__id_0
ORDER BY [h].[Home_id], [a].[Address_Id], [o].[Owner_id], [e1].[Event_id], [e2].[Event_id]
```

A few questions:

1. Is the optimization done right, or am I missing something?
2. I can see the `events` table joined twice, exactly the same, but I'm not sure why?
3. At the bottom there is an order row, even though the LINQ does not include any ordering, does this affect performance?
4. With the optimization, I'm also trying to update from .NET 5 to .NET 8. Will .NET 8 perform better with SQL Server 2022 or are the two not related? I currently use SQL Server 2019. Also, are there any known issues with LINQ in .NET 8 outside of `.contains()` and the `OPENJSON` usage? (mentioned here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32394)

Comment: Add `AsSplitQuery` to the last query - it will be improvement. Also remove all `Include`, they are useless with `Select`.

Answer (score 3):

A few of tips around working with EF and avoiding performance issues, exceptions, and other nasty behaviour:

If you want an entity with it's associated data, just eager load. Your first example could simply be replaced with:

```
 var home = context.Instance.Homes
    .Include(x => x.Seller)
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .Include(x => x.Events)
    .Single(x => x.Home_id == id);
```

This would generate a single SQL statement to load the home and associated data. This produces a Cartesian Product which can be somewhat slow and resource intensive. This can be optimized in EF Core 8 via `AsSplitQuery()`:

```
 var home = context.Instance.Homes
    .Include(x => x.Seller)
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .Include(x => x.Events)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Single(x => x.Home_id == id);
```

Which will generate separate SQL statements for the eagerly loaded entities, removing the Cartesian Product results. This works fine in an example like this. You need to be careful with `AsSplitQuery` when loading multiple top level entities especially when sorting and/or pagination is involved.

One thing you should absolutely avoid in EF is exposing public setters for collection navigation properties. Code like:

```
home.Events = _context.Instance
                     .Events
                     .Where(x => x.Home_id == home.Home_id)
                     .ToList();
```

Is extremely bad. When working with EF entities, change tracking is a very important feature and if you ever set a collection to a new instance you break change tracking. In your Home entity, your Events and any other Collection-based navigation properties should be treated as read only references:

```
public class Home
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; protected set; } = new List<Event>();

}
```

Make the setter inaccessible, and auto-initialize the default state to a new collection ready to go for new Home instances. EF will populate this collection when reading data, and it prevents accidental or erroneous code from breaking the change tracking.

Lastly, your last example is something called projection. However with projection you should define a new concrete class(es) (ViewModel or DTO) to represent the data you want to project to, even if for the most part this looks like the entity classes. The primary reason *not* to project into new instances of the entity classes is to avoid confusion about what instances of Home etc. are actual tracked entities, and what instances are detached, and potentially only partially populated instances. If I have a function that takes in a Home, it should expect to be getting an actual tracked Home entity that is complete. If I want to optimize reads to populate a simplified version of a Home and related data, this should be a HomeViewModel or HomeDTO. This means there is no confusion between methods that expect to work against entities vs. methods that expect the projections.  When projecting with `Select` you do not need `Include` and you should absolutely avoid any situation where you mix entities with projections. For instance if I create a HomeDTO and want a list of Events, I create a collection of EventDTO in the HomeDTO to populate, I do not store Event entity references within the DTO.

Things like serialization on entities can be a huge performance killer if Lazy Loading is enabled, and can lead to seemingly inconsistent behaviour (incomplete data) when Lazy Loading is disabled and an Eager Load `Include` is forgotten. Projecting to ViewModels/DTOs help avoid these problems by letting EF populate an instance of what the consumer needs, and building an SQL statement specific to just the tables and columns that are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that aligns with the data your function needs. It's unlikely that you need all fields from all related tables. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
public class HomeObjDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBuilt { get; set; }
    
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressAddress { get; set; }
    public string AddressUprn { get; set; }
    public string AddressTown { get; set; }
    public string AddressPostcode { get; set; }
    
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    
    public List<EventDTO> Events { get; set; }
}

public class EventDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}


public HomeObjDTO ReadByIdWithObjects(int id)
{
    var homeDTO = _context.Instance.Homes
        .Include(x => x.Seller)
        .Include(x => x.Owner)
        .Include(x => x.Address)
        .Include(x => x.Events)
        .Where(x => x.Home_id == id)
        .Select(x => new HomeObjDTO
        {
            Id = x.Home_id,
            Number = x.Number,
            Color = x.Color,
            DateBuilt = x.DateBuilt,
            AddressId =  x.Address.Id,
            AddressUprn = x.Address.UPRN,
            AddressAddress = x.Address.Address_Address,
            AddressTown = x.Address.Town,
            AddressPostcode = x.Address.Postcode,
            OwnerId = x.Owner.Owner_id,
            OwnerName = x.Owner.Owner_Name,
            Events = x.Events.Select(e => new EventDTO
            {
                Id = e.Event_id,
                OwnerId = e.Owner_id,
                Created = e.Event_created,
                Text = e.Event_text
            }).ToList()
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return homeDTO;
}
```

This approach reduces the amount of data retrieved from the database, improving query performance. Make sure to adjust the data types in the DTOs as needed. I ran tests locally accessing the SQL Server, and it was quite fast. However, the improvement may vary depending on your database, data, and relationships.

Edit:

I changed my solution after seeing @Steve Py's comment, it looked like this:

```
public HomeObjDTO ReadByIdWithObjects(int id)
{
    var homeDTO = _context.Instance.Homes
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Seller)
        .Include(x => x.Owner)
        .Include(x => x.Address)
        .AsSplitQuery()
        .Where(x => x.Home_id == id)
        .Select(x => new HomeObjDTO
        {
            Id = x.Home_id,
            Number = x.Number,
            Color = x.Color,
            DateBuilt = x.DateBuilt,
            AddressId =  x.Address.Id,
            AddressUprn = x.Address.UPRN,
            AddressAddress = x.Address.Address_Address,
            AddressTown = x.Address.Town,
            AddressPostcode = x.Address.Postcode,
            OwnerId = x.Owner.Owner_id,
            OwnerName = x.Owner.Owner_Name
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        
        homeDTO.Events =?? new List<EventDTO>()
        homeDTO.Events = _context.Instance.Events
                                            .AsNoTracking()
                                            .Where(e => e.Owner_id == homeDTO.OwnerId)
                                            .Select(e => new EventDTO
                                            {
                                                Id = e.Event_id,
                                                OwnerId = e.Owner_id,
                                                Created = e.Event_created,
                                                Text = e.Event_text
                                            }).ToList()

    return homeDTO;
}
```

I attach my test print's:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is not Ai solution, i apply in my job. @Fastnlight you are crazy ?

Comment: Answer is bad, that's why I have downvoted. 1) you do not understand what `Include` do,  it is not needed in this query. 2 ) You do not know when to put `AsNoTracking` and why, with `Select` it is useless.  3 ) you have a little improved query by splitting explicitly, why not `AsSplitQuery`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I made an edit to my post after seeing Steve's comment, I left it as history.

Comment: Solution is still bad, you have missed all my comments. `ASplitQuery` works ONLY for collection navigation properties. Real answer is add `AsSplitQuery` to original question's query and everything should work faster without any strange code.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Show me the code!

I would love to see you replicate the example and compare it in the benchmark. Otherwise, Talk my hand...

Comment: Get last query from question and just add `AsSplitQuery`.   `...       Events = x.Events,
    }).AsSplitQuery().FirstOrDefault();`